# Generate java classes from castor mapping file

Tags: java, code-generation, castor

I have this question:
Is it possible to generate java code from castor xml mapping files?

I have just a bunch of xml files and no xsds.

I've tried searching SO and google, and couldn't find anything.
Does anyone know if castor can do this?